# Como implementar aplicaçao rest em produçao? (Servidores web ou cloud)

Tags: java, android, web-service, rest, tomcat

Galera, sou novo em baixa plataforma e estou aprendendo java fazendo um pequeno projeto android que consulta banco de dados, mas vi que android nao é legal se comunicar com banco de dados diretamente, então aprendi criar uma api rest usando netbeans, tomcat e glassfish. Até agora tudo certo, estou usando localhost e minha aplicaçao android consegue se comunciar via https com a api rest tranquilamente, porem agora quero colocar isso em um servidor web, ( para que eu possa colocar o app na play store) ,  principalmente cloud, mas nao faço ideia de como promover isso para a web, tentei via bluemix e não consegui e nao encontro nada sobre rest em produçao.
Voces tem algum tutorial? Pode me indicar servidores ? Vi que a amzon está forte nesse seguimento.

Uma duvida, os servidores vao gerar as URLs https para meu app requisitar ? (Como o glassfish faz)

Sou muito leigo nesse assunto, nao estou usando maven, mas posso aprender e começar a utilizar asap..

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Para hospedagem nós temos usado a [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) e estamos bem satisfeitos. Em relação as urls, depois de feito o deploy da aplicação, altere as configurações do cliente android, substituindo o localhost pelo dominio/ip do servidor (por exemplo: localhost:8080/clientes para ip_do_servidor/clientes) seguindo as convenções de protocolo do REST (post = create, put = update, delete = delete, get = select)